# Common expression for $j$th "Folgenglied" (e.g. $x_j$) in English?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, mathematical-german

Let $x \in X^{\mathbb N}$ be an arbitrary sequence, where $X$ is some non-empty set.

For $j \in \mathbb N$, what would you typically call $x_j \equiv x(j)$ in English?

In German, I'd likely say "*das $j$-te Folgenglied*" (direct translation $\approx$ *the $j$th sequence member*). However, I'm not sure what common expressions for $x_j$ exist in English.

Comment: Huh I translated it as " episode member". Folgen means episode, right?

Comment: No, episode is for a movie series, so "Staffel" and "Folge" in German. In English, I see most often "take the $j$-th member of the sequence $(a_i)$." For example, see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/sequences-A-i-i-1-n-and-calculating-the-j-th-member-of-A-n-from-the-elements-of-A_fig2_220905071).

Comment: Oh. So you're saying it depends on the context @DietrichBurde

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational: If you think the multiple translations of "Folge" are interesting, just wait until you look up "Glied" ;)

Comment: Oh that was meaning beyond my expectation ;)

Comment: As Dietrich Burde says, $j$-th member of the sequence.  Or $j$-th element, or $j$-th item are also synonyms and frequently used.  You can even get away with $j$-th term of the sequence if you like.

Comment: In the precalculus class I am teaching in Canada right now, the textbook calls this the *$j$-th term of the sequence*, and I concur.